# Magento - Adding Register URL inside a href

Tags: php, magento, if-statement

Hey I am very new to PHP, I come from a design background, but I am now trying to figure out some of the PHP myself.

I have a problem with a if else statement where I would like users to register to view product prices (Logged in users can view prices, but other users are presented with a 'please register' blurb). But I can't figure out how to get the register URL to echo inside the a href tag.

Here is my code:

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);} else { echo '<a href="#">Please register to view prices</a>';}
?>


<?php echo Mage::helper('persistent')->getCreateAccountUrl($this->getCreateAccountUrl()) ?>
```

The code on the bottom is used to call the register URL. I can't figure out how to properly place the register URL code into the a href tags without it generating some sort of error. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
 } 
 else { 
    echo '<a href="'.Mage::helper('persistent')->getCreateAccountUrl($this->getCreateAccountUrl()).'">Please register to view prices</a>';
 } 

?>
```

Try this code. Basically you want to join strings together.  Mage::helper... returns a string.  So join that result with the static string which includes your html for a link.

Bit to deep for this question but really I would not use echo to display any html. Where possible just use php to display dynamic content. e.g.

```
<?php 
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
 } 
 else {  ?>
    <a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('persistent')->getCreateAccountUrl($this->getCreateAccountUrl());?>">Please register to view prices</a>
 <?php } ?>
```