# I want to put register page link in magento subcategory

Tags: php, magento

basically I want to call `register/sign-up` page link in `magento subcategory` (from dropdown link)..

I have tried two things

1) Creating `custom url rewriting` from `magento backend`

2) Creating a `static block` and putting `register.phtml` in that block, and calling the static block in category..

in `url rewriting` I am not getting the page, actually `sign-up` page is getting redirected to `category page` :P...
and in `static block` the form is not loading giving error `call to undefined member function`...

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980252/magento-adding-register-url-inside-a-href

Comment: @himansu thanks but this cant help me out..